# Error in SQL Syntax (MYSQL 5.0)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, mysql5, mysql-5.0

Does anybody know what is wrong in this MYSQL 5.0 syntax?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS target (
  _id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  time timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  map_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  left int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  top int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  status tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  temperature int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  humidity float DEFAULT NULL,
  lum int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (map_id) REFERENCES map(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

I'll show you the error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'left INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
  top INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
  status tinyint(1) NOT' at line 5

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I write SQL for a table that shares the same name as a protected keyword in MySql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706920/how-can-i-write-sql-for-a-table-that-shares-the-same-name-as-a-protected-keyword)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `left` is a [MySQL 5.0 reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html).  Also, even though you can escape the field name, it's never a great idea to use reserved words in a table definition.

Answer (score 2):

you must write it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS target (
  _id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  time timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  map_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `left` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  top int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  status tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  temperature int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  humidity float DEFAULT NULL,
  lum int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (map_id) REFERENCES map(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

look at the `` (backticks) characters in left row !

Answer (score 0):

You're using reserved words as field names. You can do that, but then you have to properly escape them, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS target (
  `_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `map_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `left` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `top` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `temperature` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `humidity` decimal(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lum` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (map_id) REFERENCES map(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

My advise would be to avoid reserved names.